# Advanced type hints in Python - how do I avoid mypy being angry when the type is not specific enough

Tags: mypy, type-hinting, python-typing

I have some functions that return dictionaries:

```py
def get_metadata_from_file(filepath:str)->dict[str, bool|dict[str, Any]]:
   '''Get metadata about a file if it exists'''

   answer = {}

   if os.path.isfile(filepath):
       answer['exists'] = True
       answer['metadata'] = { dict of metadata attributes }
   else: 
       answer['exists'] = False
       answer['metadata'] = {}

   return answer
```

Later in other functions I have issues:

```py
def get_creation_time(filepath:str)->str|None:

    metadata = get_metadata_from_file(filepath)

    if metadata['exists']:
        return metadata['metadata']['created_at'] # Mypy gets angry here
    else:
        return None
```

Clearly the program's logic handles the case where the file does not exist, but Mypy is concerned that the `metadata['metadata']['created_at']` key might not exist / that metadata['metadata'] will be a boolean.

I'm sure there is a solution to this, what is the recommended approach?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using type checkers like `mypy`, you should always try to define the expected types
as precisely as possible. There are, however, situations where defining all
the expected types becomes counterproductive and sometimes impossible.
For these situations, you might want to specify broad type hints, like `Any`, or
`object`, although these should be avoided as much as possible.

#### Solutions to Address `mypy` Concerns

Your code specifically contains a nested dictionary with mixed types, which
`mypy` finds ambiguous based on your function signatures and handling inside
the functions. You could solve the `mypy` warnings by implementing the following
changes:

1. **Use TypedDict for Precise Type Definitions**: `TypedDict` is useful when you want to
   specify types for keys in a dictionary. This allows `mypy` to understand
   what keys are expected in the dictionary and their corresponding value types.
2. **Explicit Type Checks and Use of `.get()` Method**: Before accessing a nested key,
   check if the key exists or use the `.get()` method of dictionaries which can
   return `None` (or a default value you provide) if the key is not present.
   This is a safer way to access values in dictionaries and can satisfy `mypy`
   that you've handled potential `KeyError`s.
3. **Optional Types for Dictionary Values**: Indicate that dictionary values,
   especially in nested structures, can be `None` by using `Optional[type]`.

#### Revised Example with the Above Solutions

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Optional, Any
import os


class FileMetadata(TypedDict):
    exists: bool
    metadata: Optional[dict[str, Any]]  # Adjust Any to be more specific if possible


def get_metadata_from_file(filepath: str) -> FileMetadata:
    """Get metadata about a file if it exists"""
    answer: FileMetadata = {'exists': False, 'metadata': None}

    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        answer['exists'] = True
        # Example metadata dict. Replace with actual metadata extraction.
        answer['metadata'] = {'created_at': '2023-01-01'}

    return answer 


def get_creation_time(filepath: str) -> Optional[str]:
    metadata = get_metadata_from_file(filepath)

    if metadata['exists'] and metadata['metadata']:
        # Use .get() for safer access to the 'created_at' key
        return metadata['metadata'].get('created_at')
    return None
```

The refactored code above should address the `mypy` issues you're experiencing:

```
❯ mypy "stackoverflow_question.py"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Nice, the use of TypedDict looks cleaner than my workarounds with dataclasses.

Comment: fwiw `object` is just as type-safe as any other type (though you can't do a lot with one). `Any` is the unsafe one

Comment: Definitely a great answer if refactoring is not feasible/possible, but in general use of dictionaries for such cases should be avoided. Code will likely be much cleaner with dataclasses (or Pydantic models, if some dicts are received as user input and should be validated), and `mypy` will be happier on average.